# how to authorizate use google-api-ruby-client

Tags: ruby, oauth, google-api

i am using google api for ruby, but not know how to start, just give me an ABC example someone, thanks very much?

Comment: Have you tried: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-ruby-client/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are creating a Service Account application to access Google Analytics.

1. Register it with Google through https://code.google.com/apis/console. 
   On API Access tab, click Create client ID, choose Service Account. Store the key file Google will generate, and remember the password for that key.
2. Here is some code to get you started

   ```
   require 'rubygems'
   require 'google/api_client'

   api_client = Google::APIClient.new
   path_to_key_file ="/path/to/key/file-privatekey.p12"
   passphrase = "google_generated_password"
   key = Google::APIClient::PKCS12.load_key(path_to_key_file, passphrase)
   ```

Once a key is available, initialize the asserter with your client ID (email in APIs console) 
and authorization scopes.

```
asserter = Google::APIClient::JWTAsserter.new(
   'super_long_client_id_from_api_console@developer.gserviceaccount.com',
   'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly',
   key)

# To request an access token, call authorize:
api_client.authorization = asserter.authorize()
puts api_client.authorization.access_token
```

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-ruby-client/wiki/ServiceAccounts

Comment: I get this: `Authorization failed. Server message: { "error" : "invalid_grant" }`.

I've heard people say to change the grant mode to offline, but is there a way to do that from the ruby gem?

Answer (score 0):

I've answered something similar in a couple of other posts I found that were like this one... so incase its relevant, for ruby, using the google-api-client (for any of the google apis), there's a few ins and outs with authentication when using an api key as opposed to OAuth...

I've outlined this process (using an api key server side) at [the code abode](http://thecodeabode.blogspot.com.au/2012/07/google-api-ruby-client-authorizing-with.html).

You have to explicitly set the authorzation param to nil when constructing the client, otherwise the gem tries to use OAuth to authenticate, so if calling from a server using an api key only, you will always get a 401 Unauthorized.

[the code abode - google-api-client for ruby](http://thecodeabode.blogspot.com.au/2012/07/google-api-ruby-client-authorizing-with.html)